# Node js write to file

Tags: javascript, node.js

can someone please help me and look at the code, which is supposed to write contents of one txt file to another file, using Node.js ?

Problem is, after running the script, it just outputs the contents of the first file to the console, instead of writing it to another file.

Here is the code:

```
var fs = require('fs')


var readMe = fs.readFileSync('treasure-chamber-report.txt','utf8');
fs.writeFileSync('upis.txt', readMe);
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. When running the code with a file named 'treasure-chamber-report.txt' in the same directory, another file is created with the same content called 'upis.txt'. The console log you see, is that by any chance an error?

Comment: You are right. I ran the file through node.js again and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: I attempted the asynchronous code but it throws an error. Can you please tell me why ? Here is the code:

Comment: var fs = require('fs')
 

fs.readFile('treasure-chamber-report.txt','utf8', function(err,data){
  fs.writeFile('upis.txt', data)

});

Comment: Please modify the question to show the code giving the error as well as the error that you are getting.